# Managing Complex State Structure for Nested Components in React Redux

Tags: react-redux

In my React Redux project, I'm facing a challenge in managing a complex state structure within the Redux store. The scenario involves a parent component named "court orders," which contains a component called "child information." The "court orders" component can have multiple instances of "child information," and each "child information" instance has details related to another component called "address details."

For clarity, I've represented the structure using a simplified JSON object:

```js
 courtsOrders: {
  courtName: string,
  date: string,
  state: string,

  childInformation: {
    name: string,
    birthdate: string,
    
    address: {
      street: string,
      city: string,
      state: string,
    },
  },

  address: {
    street: string,
    city: string,
    state: string,
  },
}
```

In this model, it's specified that there can be multiple instances of both "child information" components and "address" components within "court orders." Importantly, each of these components has its own separate Redux slice, which has been pre-defined.

Any guidance, examples, or best practices on how to structure the Redux store, along with relevant actions and reducers, would be greatly appreciated.

I'm seeking advice on how to structure my Redux store to handle this complexity effectively. Specifically, I need a model that allows me to manage and update specific instances of "court orders," "child information," and "address" components.

Comment: If you want multiple "instances" of "childInformation" and "address" objects then I'd recommend using an array instead of a single object.